# Comment environment inside another comment environment

Tags: environments, comments

I need to comment a chapter but I have a paragraph commented in that chapter.
When I type:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
\newchapter{Chapter 1}
My tesis...
\begin{comment}
text...
\end{comment}
more text...
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Latex show the follow message: `LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{comment}.`

Comment: Where is the `\end{document}`, please provide a complete example (MWE). Is it possible to have a comment in a comment (I don't know)

Comment: You cannot nest `comment` environments. By the way, what would it be useful for?

Comment: Maybe  are you looking really for the  `\includeonly` command?